# How to create stubs for auto-completion support in Webstorm?

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

Let's assume that I have a small JS library that uses custom HTML attributes to … do certain tasks. Something like `my-support-tag="blahblah"`.

I noticed that just by importing a minified Angular js file as a JS lib in Webstorm's settings, I get attribute auto-completion, all the `ng-*` attribs show up when editing HTML files.

How can I create some stubs or support files or whatever I need so that Webstorm offers auto-complete support for my own `my-`prefixed HTML attribs too?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can add these attributes to the list of custom HTML attributes in WebStorm.
Hit alt-enter on the unknown attribute and select Add attribute to custom HTML attributes:
[image]

Or go to Preferences | Editor | Inspections - Unknown HTML tag attribute and add a comma-separated list of all custom attributes in the inspection's Options.